# Angular 2 - Get the old value

Tags: angular

I want to get the old value of steps, not the latest after I clicked on the submit, on my init() I have this code

```
export class BakingProcedureItemComponent implements OnInit {
    steps: Array<string> = [];

    ngOnInit() {

        this.steps.push("test");
        this.currentSteps = this.steps;
        if(!this.isNew){
            this.service.get(id).subscribe( item => {
                this.steps = item;
            } );
        }
    }

    onSubmit({value, valid}: {value: BakingProcedure, valid: boolean}): void {
        console.log(this.currentSteps);  //output ['test'] not []
    }
}
```

it output latest value not `['test']`. How to get the old value, before it got pushed.

Comment: Copy the array, eg using `slice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
this.currentSteps = this.steps;
```

to

```
this.currentSteps = this.steps.slice(0);
```

`Array.slice()` will create a new instance for your array.

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bvJtgFuPLIvwgVtDZQWJ?p=preview)** (open console to confirm the result.)

Comment: check another sample, just want the old value, like in the PHP

Comment: @StormSpirit have you tried my suggestion since they are the same.

Comment: @StormSpirit there's no special for string, just keep it in another variable.